# Application insights missing UserId property when using Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-front-door

Almost all request telemetry for my .NET core API is missing the `UserId` property. I've got an Angular SPA making HTTP requests to my API via Azure Front Door. The only request telemetry that has an `UserId` property is traffic that is not passed through Azure Front Door. To be precise: it's SignalR requests directly to the API. I have a feeling that our Angular app passes telemetry to our Application Insights (for the front-end only) and that in our other Application Insights (for the back-end only) things don't seem to line up. The dependency telemetry in the front-end is to a different URL than the request telemetry in the back-end is receiving. Azure Front Door is set to forward requests, so it does the request it receives again to the right destination.

Schematic overview of HTTP requests missing the `UserId` property in the back-end:

```
---------                          --------                       --------
|Angular|  GET domain.com/api1     | Front|  GET domain2.com/api  | Back |
|  app  | -----------------------> | Door | --------------------> | End  |
---------                          --------                       --------
```

Schematic overview of HTTP requests containing the `UserId` property in the back-end:

```
---------                          --------
|Angular|  GET domain2.com/signalr | Back |
|  app  | -----------------------> | End  |
---------                          --------
```

I've looked into the the request headers but I see no indication that a `UserId` is passed there and they are practically the same for requests to front door or directly to my API (hostname is the big difference there). I *think* that front door does the request with the same headers it gets the request.

First of all, are my assumptions correct? Is the problem that the URL the front-end dependency tracks is different than the back-end is receiving? If so, what can I do about this? I want to use the `UserId` for troubleshooting actions a specific user has done before he ran in to an issue (the "All available telemetry for this user session" feature).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is correlating front-end and back-end telemetry. There is a attribute operation_id which can be found on both front-end and back-end telemetries and can be used to correlate. You may want to customize both front-end and back-end telemetry to have authenticated userid. Have a look at the below resource on correlating telemetries. Hope that helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation